# Complex pattern match in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

someone please share their expertise on this complicated pattern match.

**I am not sure if it is possible in sql**

DDL

```
DECLARE @MASTERAPP TABLE
 (
     TYPE VARCHAR (50),    
     Respiration_notes VARCHAR (50)
 )

 INSERT @MASTERAPP

 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    '20 Inch-OE Size; P-275-55-20; 109S' UNION ALL-- INVALID REMARKS_2 
 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    '20 Inch-OE Size; P-275-55-20; 109S' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    '20 Inch-Plus Size; P-275-55-20; 113S; 9.5' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    '20 Inch-Plus Size; Q-888-XX-20; 113S; 9.5;Maleward,bed no 16' -- INVALID Remarks_1_Value


 DECLARE @CHILD TABLE
 (
     TYPE VARCHAR (50),    
     Remarks_1 VARCHAR (50),    
     Remarks_1_Value    VARCHAR (50),
     Remarks_2 VARCHAR (50),    
     Remarks_2_Value VARCHAR (50)
 )

 INSERT @CHILD
    SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    'LUNGS Metric',    'P-275-55-20',    'LungsService',    '111T' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    'LUNGS Metric',    'P-275-55-20',    'LungsService',    '117S' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'LUNGSLINE',    'LUNGS Metric',    'P-275-55-20',    'LungsService',    '113S'
```

i am trying to check whether Respiration_notes contain correct value or not

Respiration_notes should contain same value as in Remarks_1_Value present after first semicolon and Remarks_2_Value present after second semicolon in Respiration_notes.

common key between two table is Type.

Appreciate your suggestion.

output

```
'LUNGSLINE',    '20 Inch-OE Size; P-275-55-20; 109S' UNION ALL-- INVALID REMARKS_2_value

'20 Inch-Plus Size; Q-888-XX-20; 113S; 9.5;Maleward,bed no 16' -- INVALID Remarks_1_Value
```

Comment: This is just one of the many problems with embedding multiple pieces of data into a single column in a database (which is effectively what you - or whoever designed the database - have done). Don't do that. I'm sure that a solution can be found for this, and I'll see if I can put one up soon, but this is just the start of the headaches that you will face if you continue with this design.

Comment: I'd echo what Tom H has said about embedding multiple values in a single column.   Perhaps, the first approach would be to split the multiple values into individual columns or rows (preferably in your design, but can be done using a function with existing structure) - that would make your query a lot more simple.

Comment: @TomH: Thanks Tom. its client DB and we don't have any rights to change DB structure... and we are dying now... :)

Comment: @TomH . . . What you say is a good design principle.  Unfortunately, it doesn't necessarily help in solving actual problems on available data.

Comment: That doesn't make it unimportant or something that shouldn't be said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this will give you what you need:

```
SELECT
    MA.TYPE,
    MA.Respiration_notes
FROM
    @MASTERAPP MA
LEFT OUTER JOIN @CHILD C ON
    C.TYPE = MA.TYPE AND
    MA.Respiration_notes LIKE '%; ' + C.Remarks_1_Value + '; ' + C.Remarks_2_Value + '%'
WHERE
    C.TYPE IS NULL
```

Keep in mind that this relies on the **exact** format that you have in your examples. If other text is inserted between the two remarks or if there is additional whitespace, etc. then this will not work. Another reason why this sort of text matching is precarious at best - it's very fragile.

Comment: Thanks Tom... thanks a ton... i just checking it on full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `like`.  I think this is the logic:

```
select ma.*, c.*
from @masterapp ma left join
     @child c
     on ma.Respiration_notes like '[^;]; ' + c.Remarks_1_Value + '; ' + Remarks_2_Value + ';%'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not giving expected Result.

Comment: @akhrot . . . Probably because you have spaces after your semicolons.  You may need to play with it to get it to work on your actual data.

Comment: oh!! but this is a small set of my real data. Unfortunately of same fashion. space need to be retain after semicolon.... my bad luck... :(